# How to access related record field values from apex call

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wire

I have an object called Customer_Experience__c that is the child of a master-detail relationship to the Contact. I'm able to view the entire record in the console log but I need to assign the field values to variables in js. It keeps returning 'undefined' for introOnboSp in the console log. Any ideas?

Apex:

```
public with sharing class getConsultantTrackerInfo {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Customer_Experience__c> getConsultantTrackerInfo(List<Id> recordId){
    List<Customer_Experience__c> expTracker = [SELECT Id, Intro_Onboarding_Specialist__c 
                                               FROM Customer_Experience__c 
                                               WHERE Candidate__c =:recordId];
    return expTracker;
   }
}
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getConsultantTrackerInfo from '@salesforce/apex/getConsultantTrackerInfo.getConsultantTrackerInfo';

export default class ConsultantTracker extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@api recordId;
tracker;
introOnboSp;

@wire(getConsultantTrackerInfo, {recordId : '$recordId'})
wiredTracker({data, error}){
if(data){
    console.log('data: ', data);
    this.tracker = data;
    this.introOnboSp = this.tracker.Intro_Onboarding_Specialist__c;
    console.log('introOnboSp = '+this.introOnboSp);
}
else if(error){
    console.log('error');
    console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a list of Customer_Experience__c objects but in the javascript you are attempting to use dot notation to access a field

```
this.introOnboSp = this.tracker.Intro_Onboarding_Specialist__c;
```

My advice would be to console log this.tracker and see if you are getting back a list and if you are you should use the first value like so

```
this.introOnboSp = this.tracker[0].Intro_Onboarding_Specialist__c
```

(if you are not I would check the query itself in developer console's query editor to see if the query brings back a value).

Alternatively in the apex you could return just the first value

```
    public with sharing class getConsultantTrackerInfo {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Customer_Experience__c getConsultantTrackerInfo(Id recordId){
    Customer_Experience__c expTracker = [SELECT Id, Intro_Onboarding_Specialist__c 
                                               FROM Customer_Experience__c 
                                               WHERE Candidate__c =:recordId LIMIT 1];
    return expTracker;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up for me Calvin!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Customer_Experience__c> getConsultantTrackerInfo(List<Id> recordId){
```

The Apex is expecting a List of Id, but you're passing in an Id (so it can't be automatically converted to a list). This is easy to fix, though:

```
public static List<Customer_Experience__c> getConsultantTrackerInfo(Id recordId){
```

Comment: I have unfortunately tried that already and it still comes out as "introOnboSp = undefined
"

Comment: @LukeHiggins is this being placed on a Record Page? Is it a top-level component? The thing is, wire will fire twice if it loads data, once with a null parameter, and once with the loaded data. If it's not loading, make sure you're in the right context.